# A div added on the page witohut even having it in the code

Tags: html

I'd like to get some help. The problem is that I continue getting a "div" on my web page without even having it in my code. If I style the "div", for some reason, it appears without being even presented in my code, and it appearts at the bottom of the page. And if I add "div" then it's doubled without any spacing.
I know the question might be really stupid, but I don't really know what to do.
Below you'll find the code and the link to the sreenshot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Document</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bullet-icon.css">
<style> 
div {
        background-image: radial-gradient(red, pink);
        width: 500px;
        height: 300px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: the screenshot of my web page]

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it in last opera, last chrome and ie 9 - there is no this issue. Seems like it is done by some extension of your browser, browser itself, or http server which you are using.

Try to change browser, then:

- if issue still here - check your http server
- else - check your extensions

Comment: I've tried using another browser and everything went just fine. Looks like there's something with my chrome. Thank you for your help. 
I wouldn't even think to try another browser.